# Give persmission to use AWS KMS key to another account

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I created KMS key by using KMS client (PHP).

```
    `new KmsClient([
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $awsKey,
            'secret' => $awsSecret,
        ],
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ]);`
```

Now I want to share this key with some other users. I have their Account IDs,

How can I do that, by using RDS api?

Nothing works. I'm also unable to find any examples in GitHub examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a policy to give permission to another account access it.
Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html) for more details.
`444455556666` is other account's id.

```json
{
    "Sid": "Allow an external account to use this KMS key",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"
        ]
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But How do I allow this key for multiple users. When I tries, AWS gives error.

Comment: `AWS` in `Principal` is an array it accepts multiple accounts. You just need to use `root` in a single account